# trying to image new machine with 2 SSDs in RAID 0

Tags: windows-7, ssd, raid-0

I have a machine that we ordered from dell that we are putting our company's image on. This is a custom build with 2 256GB SSDs that I am trying to put on a raid 0 configuration. The problem I am running into is that the computer will not boot into Windows unless AHCI is enabled, which of course, nixes the raid config. If you have it on the raid config, after we install the image, Windows starts to boot but freezes, goes to a quick blue screen, and then attempts to reboot again.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If you need any more information or would like me to provide anything additional, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: How are you applying the image? Is the image created for a RAID 0 array?

Comment: Your image needs the RAID drivers installed into it, BEFORE you enable the RAID in the BIOS. You _may_ be able to image it first, and THEN get the RAID running --  See [Set up raid 1 after OS installation](http://superuser.com/questions/490668/set-up-raid-1-after-os-installation), [How to install RAID drivers on already installed Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/155939/how-to-install-raid-drivers-on-already-installed-windows-7)

Comment: Can you clarify that you first are building the raid array, then trying to install the image? It sounds like you may have already installed the image on a drive and are trying to retroactively add a second and make it raid 0?

Comment: thanks for the quick replies

so the image does not have the raid drivers installed on it, that will likely be the first thing i'll try

abraxas - no the raid array was built first, then we apply the image to the new logical volume

Answer (score 0):

Windows is quite stubborn about its underlying data-structure. I do not know the specific reason, but I do know that changing stuff on the disk level like switching between IDE and AHCI mode, major changes to Raid-Setups and stuff like that cause the machine to stop booting properly. I had some experience with this in the past, as I tried to port a Windows install from a single disk installation to RAID1.  The image must be taken from a machine that has a very similar (or identical) setup, so that includes the proper drivers and settings.

You are probably best of with setting up the machine manually instead of "restoring" it of a image.